# missing value in return (MIPS)

Tags: assembly, mips, qtspim

I want to make **additions** using the **function**. And I use **MIPS-Simulator**.
for example: a + b and a + c in a function.
My codes look like this :

> .data
>
> x : .word 5
>
> y : .word 2
>
> k : .word 9
>
> nl: .asciiz "\n"
>
> .text
>
> .globl main
>
> **main :**
>
> addi $sp, $sp, -12
>
> sw $ra, 0($sp)
>
> sw $s0, 4($sp)
>
> sw $s1, 8($sp)
>
> jal C
>
> move $s0, $v0 # **my Expectation =** save the value from **$v0** in **s0**, also **7**
>
> move $s1, $v1 # **my Expectation =** save the value from **$v1** in **s1**, also **14**
>
> li $v0, 1  #**print the value $s1**
>
> move $a0, $s0          # **my Expectation didn't come true :(**
>
> syscall
>
> li $v0, 4
>
> la, $a0, nl # it just a **newline**
>
> syscall
>
> li $v0, 1 #**print the value $s1**
>
> move $a0, $s1        # **my Expectation didn't come true :(**
>
> syscall
>
> li $v0, 10
>
> syscall
>
> lw $ra, 0($sp)
>
> lw $s0, 4($sp)
>
> lw $s1, 8($sp)
>
> addi $sp, $sp, 12
>
> jr $ra
>
> **C:**
>
> addi $sp, $sp, -12
>
> sw $ra, 0($sp)
>
> sw $t1, 4($sp)
>
> sw $t2, 8($sp)
>
> lw $t1, x
>
> lw $t2, y
>
> jal A
>
> move $v0, $v0 #the result will be **7** and will be saved in **$v0** because **x + y = 5 + 2 = 7**
>
> li $v0, 0
>
> lw $t1, x
>
> lw $t2, k
>
> jal A
>
> move $v1, $v0 #the result will be **14** and will be saved in **$v1** also because **x + k = 5 + 9 = 14**
>
> lw $ra, 0($sp)
>
> lw $t1, 4($sp)
>
> lw $t2, 8($sp)
>
> addi $sp, $sp, 12
>
> jr $ra
>
> **A:** #**here will be an addition function**
>
> add $v0, $t1, $t2
>
> jr $ra

**function** A and C **it has been set and can not be deleted** and as result in **function A** the Register **$v0** it also has been set. And when I run my code, the result will be:

> 14
>
> 14

which should produce value :

> 7
>
> 14

**Question :** what have i done? what's missing in my code?

**P.S :** to understand more clearly, please see my comments in my code.

Comment: `li $v0, 10` `syscall` is app termination, you don't need to do anything after it, like restoring stack, and returning (although for ordinary function you would have to). It's more common to use ordinary MIPS calling convention, where arguments for function are in `a#` registers (not `t1` and `t2`) and `s#` registers are preserved by functions, `t#` are free for modification, and returning values are in `v0` (`v0:v1` for 64b values). But as is, in `C` (fugly name for function) you receive value in `v0`, put it into `v0` again (`move $v0, $v0`), and overwrite it with zero `li $v0, 0`.

Comment: BTW, there's always zero available in `$0` (also having an alias `$zero`), although using `li` is probably as good as `move $v0, $zero`. And MARS/SPIM simulators have debuggers, where you can single-step over instructions and verify values in registers against your assumptions. Losing the `7` from sight before calling `A` second time should have raised your eyebrow... (considering your previous question it looks like solid progress on your side :) good work)

Comment: But please, learn to format code properly... when you edit your question, take a short while to check all the icons in the toolbar, or even the help, especially the "{}" icon.